# Jquery Mobile default themes are reversed, a = black and b = white

Tags: jquery-mobile, themes

I decided that I wanted to learn Jquery Mobile so I set up a test site and instantly came across a weird bug, from what I've read and seen `data-theme="a"` should be the white theme and `data-theme="b"` should be the black/grey one. However, for me it's the other way around.. Have I perhaps done something wrong when downloading the library onto my site? And does this matter or should I just ignore it?

The markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Testing</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="a">
        <h1>Testing</h1>
    </div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what I get with `data-theme="a"`:

[image: theme]

Comment: @Archon Ah, that did it the trick, if you post as an answer I can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might be because your using a pretty old version of jquery mobile, I see you're referencing version 1.2.1, try version 1.4.5.